# python - logging in Multi Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I am trying to store logs from multiple threads into a single file. But in my log file, logs from different threads are getting merged. I don't want separate log files for different threads. But when one thread is writing logs to the file, the other thread should wait till the previous thread finishes writing all the logs. I have tried different ways to do so, but finally didn't find appropriate solution.

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import threading
import time
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='LogsThreadPrac.log', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def worker(val):
    print('value from the thread: {}'.format(val))
    logger.info('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print(current_thread().name)
    logger.info('value from the thread: {}'.format(val))
    time.sleep(3)
    logger.info('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

t1 = Thread(target=worker, args=[1,], name='th'+str(1))
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=worker, args=[2,], name='th'+str(2))
t2.start()
```

Comment: What is your use case? The logging module is not intended to deal with synchronisation requirements of higher layers of abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a Lock as an argument to your workers, so you manage to synchronize the threads the way you want.

```
from threading import Thread, current_thread, Lock
import threading
import time
import logging


logging.basicConfig(filename='LogsThreadPrac.log', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger_lock = Lock()

def worker(val, lock):
    print('value from the thread: {}'.format(val))
    with lock:
        logger.info('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
        print(current_thread().name)
        logger.info('value from the thread: {}'.format(val))
        time.sleep(3)
        logger.info('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
t1 = Thread(target=worker, args=[1, logger_lock], name='th'+str(1))
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=worker, args=[2, logger_lock], name='th'+str(2))
t2.start()
```

You can check more about the lock uses and examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects)

Comment: This solution is going to take at least 6 seconds to finish both workers, which is pretty much the same time it takes without using threading.

Comment: The reason is that the threads are accessing the same file and waiting for them. This is not a true concurrency design.

Comment: Guess you guys don't really understand the problem of concurrency and how did the guy wanted to apply it...